# Access to image blocked by CORS despite 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *' from public API

Tags: javascript, cors

Here is the code from https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/CORS_enabled_image I'm using to grab the image:

```
let imgURL = obj.primaryImage;
img = new Image();
img.src = imgURL;
img.crossOrigin = "Anonymous";
img.addEventListener("load", imageProcess, false);

function imageProcess() {
   const canvas = document.getElementById('imgCanvas');
   let ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
   ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
   let imgData = ctx.getImageData(5,5,1,1).data;
}
```

When I comment out both the .getImageData and the .crossOrigin lines, the image displays. However, as soon as I try to access the image data, the following CORS error appears:

```
Access to image at 'https://images.metmuseum.org/CRDImages/ad/original/ap53.226.1.jpg' from origin 'http://127.0.0.1:5500' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

If I only comment out the line containing .crossOrigin, the following error appears:

```
Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'getImageData' on 'CanvasRenderingContext2D': The canvas has been tainted by cross-origin data.
```

Because the Metropolitan Museum's API is public, the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is set to '*' on both the JSON from which I'm retrieving the link and the image itself.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Are you running this from the file system or from a server

Comment: Also [please search the error message](https://www.google.com/search?q=the+canvas+has+been+tainted+by+cross-origin+data+site:stackoverflow.com)

Comment: I'm running it from the file system right now. I've looked for hours regarding the error messages, but the only helpful information I found was on the link in my original post on working with CORS and canvases from Mozilla.

Comment: You cannot Ajax from file system

Comment: As far as I can see, there’s no Access-Control-Allow-Origin header in the response for that image, testing with `curl -i -H "Origin: https://example.com" https://images.metmuseum.org/CRDImages/ad/original/ap53.226.1.jpg`

Comment: Ok, that clears it up. When I was originally checking for the header I was looking at the wrong file. Would the best way to interact with this image on a canvas be to cache it somehow and then send it to the canvas? Or should I use middleware?

Answer (score 0):

If you have control over the domain `images.metmuseum.org`, you can add this header server-side.

If you don't, browsers will not allow you to do this. Your only option is to write server-side scripts that grab the image for you.

Comment: I don't work at the Met unfortunately, but luckily the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present for both links and is set to access requests from all domains. You can see an example here: <https://collectionapi.metmuseum.org/public/collection/v1/objects/10245>

Comment: @RawsonD. it also needs to be set on the domain that actually serves the images for this to work